# Adjusting the outline thickness of the Frame drawn around a legend

Tags: plotting, legending

I was not able to adjust the thickness of the outline of the `Frame` drawn around the `Legend`. How can I change the `Frame`'s boundary thickness?

Code:

```
pt1 = ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Contours -> {2},    ContourStyle -> Black, ContourShading -> {Red, None}];
    
pt2 = ContourPlot[2 x^2 + 3 y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},    Contours -> {9}, ContourStyle -> Black,    ContourShading -> {Green, None}];
    
PP = Legended[Show[{pt2, pt1}] ,    Placed[SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue, Magenta}, {"BP1", "BP2"}, 
        LegendLayout -> "Row",  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 17, Bold, 
          FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman Unslanted"], LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 2,FrameStyle -> {Black}] &)], {Right, Top}]]
```

Comment: `FrameStyle -> {Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[4]]}`

Comment: Hi @Syed, It worked. Thank you so much.